# Is it possible to write an image directly to Google Drive?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have searched Google Drive API reference as well as the Internet for an answer but I haven't found any.

Is it possible to write an image directly to Google Drive from Java app?
I know that you can upload files to Google Drive from local file system via Java app, but that is not what I want.

I have a Java app that is creating an image - ***BufferedImage*** object. To save in the local file system, I use ***javax.imageio.ImageIO.write*** method and it works well.
However, what I would like to do, is to somehow write that BufferedImage directly to my Google Drive so I don't have to write it to the local file system and then upload it to Google Drive.

Thanks for help :]

Comment: Note that you can also create a temporary file (in `%TEMP%`) if the part that annoys you is cluttering your folders.

Comment: I'd expect you to be able to write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then upload the data from a `ByteArrayInputStream`, without writing to a file. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Zabuzard Good point. Thanks :]
Ideally I would like to skip the file system saving part.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have not. I will try it.